# how to write multiple inputs to text file using python?

Tags: python

I'm writing a ham radio logger.
I want to write multiple inputs but with line breaks. Here's my example.

```
raw_input = question1(' text here ')
raw_input = question2(' ')
f.write(question1)
print ' '
f.write(question2)
print ' '
```

Is there a way to combine to 2 with a line break between?
I've tried

```
f.write(question1, "\n" question2, "\n")
```

but I get errors. I just want to make it shorter. I'm very new to Python.

Comment: `f.write(question1+ "\n"+ question2+"\n")` or `f.write("{}\n{}\n".format(question1,  question2 ))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`q1=raw_input('question 1:')
q2=raw_input('question 2:')
with open('a.txt','w+') as f:
    f.writelines(q1+'\n')
    f.writelines('\n')
    f.writelines(q2+'\n')`

input
question1: hello?
question2:yes!

output:
hello?
"line break"
yes!

By the way, if you want to output file with some special format, you could use json(import json). AND, BEST to use "*with*" to handle file!

Answer (score 0):

you could also append a newline char `\n` at the end of each input or store the inputs to a list and write it to a file

```
itemlist = []
itemlist.append(raw_input("Your question"))
with open("text_file","w+") as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join(itemlist))
```

note that the `with` automatically closes the open file.

Answer (score 0):

The `print` is writing to standard output, not to `f` (which I assume is an open file handle).  The `write` method does not add newlines by itself, although you could of course add one.

```
f.write(''.join(question1, '\n', question2, '\n'))
```

Joining everything into one string just for printing isn't really necessary.  You can write things piecemeal, and/or use `+` for concatenation of strings, too:

```
f.write(question1 + '\n')
f.write(question2 + '\n')
```

or even just

```
f.write(question1)
f.write('\n')
f.write(question2)
f.write('\n')
```

You could Python's string formatting to interpolate variables with formatting into strings, too:

```
f.write('{0}\n{1}\n'.format(question1, question2))
```

or the once prevalent `%` interpolation operator:

```
f.write('%s\n%s\n' % (question1, question2))
```

With Python 2.6+ you can `from __future__ import print_function` and then the Python 3 `print` function with an optional `file=` argument can be used.  This is actually what I would recommend here.  `print` adds a newline by default (though it can be turned off if you wish).

```
print(question1, file=f)
print(question2, file=f)
```

Answer (score -1):

You were on the right path, just needed to make a few changes to your code.  Try this on for size.

73s

```
question1 = raw_input('Any question? ')
question2 = raw_input('What is another question you have? ')

f = open('filename.txt', 'wb')
f.write("QUESTION 1 = " + str(question1) + "\nQUESTION 2 = " + str(question2))
f.close()
```

Output will look like this...

QUESTION 1 = What is ham radio?

QUESTION 2 = Do I need a license

Comment: Yep totally forgot that. Added now